# Invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()[2]" is: [object Text] using XPath and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm having a lot of issues understanding how to do this. What i need to do is simple, which is to flag whenever my automated google search is not able to find any search results. My code example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys('site:'+'www.pa.gov'+ ' "ADT.com" '+'\n')
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()[2]"):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

This is the link i've searched [No Results](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=UffYX6OCC4aRggeyqIKABA&q=site%3Awww.pa.gov%20%22ADT.com%22&oq=site%3Awww.pa.gov%20%22ADT.com%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DiA1jiA2DEBWgAcAB4AIABugGIAboBkgEDMC4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjj7omextDtAhWGiOAKHTKUAEAQ4dUDCAk&uact=5)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Selenium doesn't support `text()` node. You need to stop at `//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]` and get the entire text. And after extract your needed text. Or find another `xpath` which not use `text()` as node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[following-sibling::input[@value="ST"]]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

......implies that your *XPath* expression was not a valid *xpath expression*.

You need to replace:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()[2]")
```

with:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()")[2]
```

---

### Additional Considerations

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) supports *xpath-1.0* only which returns the set of node(s) selected by the *xpath*.

> You can find the [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) specifications in [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)

However the *xpath* expression:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()")[2]
```

Is a *xpath-2.0* based expression and would typically return an `object Text`. A couple of examples:

- `//@version`: selects all the version attribute nodes that are in the same document as the context node
- `../@lang`: selects the lang attribute of the parent of the context node

> You can find the [xpath-2.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0) specifications in [XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

---

### Solution

So effectively your block of code will be:

```
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]")[2]:
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now:     

a= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]")[2]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @NateLeMay You haven't provided us the HTML of the element. So it's impossible to help you further with `IndexError: list index out of range` as we can't assume how many elements were identified and placed within the list but definitely this solution addresses your initial error of **InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector**

Comment: Selenium doesn't support node `text()`

Comment: @KunLun Where did you find `text()` in my effective/proposed solution?

Comment: @KunLun Care to answer my counter question as per your comment above? Where did you find `text()` in my effective/proposed solution?

Comment: Off: Please have some patience. I'm not here all the time. On: `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()")[2]` - this xpath returns `Text` node type. Selenium support only `Element` type.

Comment: @KunLun That wasn't my question either. Where did you find `text()` in my _**effective**_ / _**proposed**_ (_read the previous word carefully_) solution?

Comment: `You need to replace: ... with: driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()")[2]` . Also your effective solution `xpath` select 2nd `//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]` Element. OP wants to get 2nd text node from `//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]`

Comment: @KunLun Definitely there is an issue with OP's xpath `//*[@id='topstuff']/div/div/p[1]/text()[2]` and being a valuable contributor you don't just publish code block as answers. To serve the broader audience you need to explain all the issues one by one.

Answer (score -1):

`Xpath` you have provided doesn't supported by selenium yet.

I believe you are capturing the error for wrong website.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and following xpath.

Induce `try..except` block to handle if any error occurs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search.send_keys('site:'+'www.pa.gov'+ ' "ADT.com" '+'\n')
try:
  Searchelement=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='topstuff']//p[@role='heading']")))
  print(True)
  print("============================")
  print(Searchelement.text)
  print("============================")
  #If you want to get specific node value then try below xpath
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='topstuff']//p[@role='heading']/span/em").text)
except:
  print(False)
```

**Console output:**

```
True
============================
Your search - site:www.pa.gov "ADT.com" - did not match any documents.
============================
site:www.pa.gov "ADT.com"
```

Comment: I think more then web scraping OP needs to understand and solve `InvalidSelectorException`. Scrapping isn't that big deal either.